# How to remove the text "undefined" that is appearing in the autocomplete search field?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a autocomplete search. If there are no results that corresponds to the search it appears the message "No results.".

And its working the message "No results" if the user introduce 3 letters that don't correspond to any result.

However it appears "undefiend" above the message "No results". Do you know how to remove that "undefiend" text?

```
$.widget( "custom.catcomplete", $.ui.autocomplete, {
    _create: function() {
        this._super();
        this.widget().menu( "option", "items", "> :not(.ui-autocomplete-category)" );
    },
    _renderMenu: function( ul, items ) {
        var that = this,

            currentCategory = "";

        $.each( items, function( index, item ) {
            var li;
            if ( item.category != currentCategory ) {
                ul.append( "<li>" + item.category + "</li>" );
                currentCategory = item.category;
            }
            li = that._renderItemData( ul, item );


            if ( item.category ) {
                li.attr( "aria-label", item.category + " : " + item.label );
            }

        });
    }
});

$("#search").catcomplete({
    source: "{{ URL::to('autocomplete-search') }}",
    minLength: 3,
    response: function(event, ui){
        if (!ui.content.length) {
            var noResult = { value:"", label:"No results." };
            ui.content.push(noResult);
        }
    },
    select: function(event, ui) {
        if(ui.item.category=="Conferences"){
            window.location.href = ui.item.url;
        }
        else{
            $.get(ui.item.url, function(result) {
                var newConferences = '';
                var placeholder = "{{route('conferences.show', ['id' => '1', 'slug' => 'demo-slug'])}}";

                $.each(result, function(index, conference) {
                    var url = placeholder.replace(1, conference.id).replace('demo-slug', conference.slug);
                    newConferences += '<div>\n' +
'                        <div class="card box-shaddow">\n' +
'                            <div class="card-body">\n' +
'                                <h5>'+conference.name+'</h5>\n' +
'                            </div>\n' +
'                    </div></div>';
                });
                $('#conferences').html(newConferences);
            }, 'json');
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: chances are you are receiving something back that does not conform to the structure you expect when generating the list `<h5>'+conference.name+'</h5>`. Have you tried debugging that part or outputting the conference variable to see what is coming back from your service search call?

Comment: Thanks, the issue is that if  there are results that correspond to the search it appears "Conferences" and below appear the conferences that correspond to the search. But if the user do a search that dont correspond to any results it appears the message "No Results", however in the place where it shows "Conferences" (if the search returns results) it shows "Undefined".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may replace the condition `if ( item.category != currentCategory )` with the condition `if ( item.category && item.category != currentCategory )`

So that when the item doesn't have any category (which is your case : 'undefined') it doesn't append a useless line to your html.